# Any CMIS explorer written in PHP?

Tags: php, open-source, ecm, cmis

I want to write (in PHP) a custom web interface over a CMIS repository.

Rather than writing it from scratch (or near-scratch using [this library](http://incubator.apache.org/chemistry/phpclient.html)), **is there an open source CMIS browsing app written in PHP** that I could reuse?

Just need browsing in folders and download files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an independent package as I would have hoped, but Drupal has a CMIS extension that does the work:

http://drupal.org/project/cmis